# Block internet if vpn connection drops

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ufw, gufw

Trying to set up gufw so that it if my vpn connection drops, my computer won't be able to access the internet any more.

My plan was to block all outgoing, but allow only a connection to the IP of my vpn server, but I find when the firewall is implemented I can't load sites even if the vpn is connected.

[image: Gufw settings]

Above are the settings I am currently trying (partially hidden IP is my vpn server), what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which type of vpn you use? [pptp, ipsec, openvpn ...]

Comment: openvpn client and server

Answer (score 3):

You can do that just by using the ufw GUI:

- Configure ufw to globally deny outgoing traffic (just like you did)
- Add the following two rules, given that `eth0` is your public interface, `tun0` is the interface created by the VPN and `xxx.xxx.68.138` is your VPN IP:

  1. Allow to connect to the VPN IP through the public interface: add a rule with `Policy=Allow`, `Direction=Out`, `Interface=eth0` and `To=xxx.xxx.68.138`
  2. Allow everything through the VPN interface: add a rule with `Policy=Allow`, `Direction=Out`, `Interface=tun0` and `To=0.0.0.0/0`

That's all!

You almost did it, you just forgotten to allow outgoing traffic through the VPN, because globally denying outgoing traffic applies on all interfaces, including the one created by the VPN.

By the way, I suggest you to globally deny incoming traffic, this will prevent an evil person or a bot running on your network to hack into your computer by exploiting a bug or a misconfiguration of a running network service (by default, Ubuntu runs some network services listening on all interfaces, not only the local).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

You wish to change `ufw` rules based on `interface` status.

Nice place for this kind of action is in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` and `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

You can in this folder put some script and make action. For example put this script in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` to change `ufw` rules every time when `tun0`go down.

Make script called `script` with execute permissions `755`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-down.d/script
```

Script is

```
# Check interface
[ "$IFACE" != "tun0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw allow out to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Change permision of script

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-down.d/script
```

In `script` `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` represent ip of your `vpn` server

When `vpn` reconnect you need again to change `ufw` rules. 
Make one more script aka `script2`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script2
```

Script is something like this

```
# Check interface
[ "$IFACE" != "tun0" ] || exit 0
# Do something
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
#also you can add more ufw rules ...
sudo ufw ....
```

Change permision of script

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script2
```

First script will if `tun0` go down make default outgoing police to deny but will allow access to `vpn` server. Second script will change default outgoing police to `allow`

Comment: As proven by the [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/946455/88802), one can specify the interface name in the firewall rules. This eliminates any form of dynamic rules based on connection state, making it much more reliable.